# In python..looking for a simple code to output string from datetime and float from a list

Tags: python, datetime, strptime, strftime

I would like to loop through each average(index[0]) and each hour(index[1]) (in this order) in the first five lists of:
a = [[38.59, '15'], [23.81, '02'], [21.52, '20'], [16.8, '16'], [16.01, '21'], [14.74, '13'], [13.44, '10'], [13.24, '18'], [13.23, '14'], [11.46, '17']]

I would like to use the str.format() method to print the hour and average in the following format:
output str = "15:00: 38.59 average comments per post"

To format the hours, I can use the datetime.strptime() constructor to return a datetime object and then use the strftime() method to specify the format of the time.

To format the average, I can use {:.2f} to indicate that just two decimal places should be used.
How can I accomplish this with 2-3 lines of coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

a = [[38.59, '15'], [23.81, '02'], [21.52, '20'], [16.8, '16'], [16.01, '21'], [14.74, '13'], [13.44, '10'], [13.24, '18'], [13.23, '14'], [11.46, '17']]
for elem in a[:5]:
    dtObj = dt.strptime(elem[1], '%H')
    timeString = dt.strftime(dtObj, '%H:%M')
    roundedAverageString = "{0:.2f}".format(elem[0])
    print("{}: {} average comments per post".format(timeString, roundedAverageString))
```

output example:
15:00: 38.59 average comments per post

Comment: I didn't realize that you wanted the minutes in the output too, sorry. Does the code work now?

Comment: It worked! Yes, minutes are required in the printout, but they all will be 00 since only hours are mentioned in the list.

Comment: Someone also brought to my attention that you only wanted the first 5 pairs in the list, so I changed the for loop. You should probably look at Mark's answer however, as his solution is more elegant

Comment: I did use [:5] in my code and also had edited the earlier code to add .2f which matched with your edited code. Thank you for a quick input.

Answer (score 1):

Using `datetime` is overkill given the data:

```
data = [[38.59, '15'], [23.81, '02'], [21.52, '20'], [16.8, '16'], [16.01, '21'], [14.74, '13'], [13.44, '10'], [13.24, '18'], [13.23, '14'], [11.46, '17']]
for ave,hr in data[:5]:
    print(f'{hr}:00: {ave:5.2f} average comments per post')
```

```
15:00: 38.59 average comments per post
02:00: 23.81 average comments per post
20:00: 21.52 average comments per post
16:00: 16.80 average comments per post
21:00: 16.01 average comments per post
```